# Cancel sharepoint workflow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

when cancel sharepoint workflow by web browser or programatically by code

```
SPWorkflowManager.CancelWorkflow()
```

All task in my workflow task list was deleted, where i can turn off this, i need this task to reporting.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way SharePoint works, canceling a workflow deletes all related tasks, but the workflow history is kept. Do not rely on tasks as a proof that something did or did not happen.